TinyMCE (basic setup) missing skins and themes in Angular 18.2
I installed the package via npm: npm i tinymce --save version 7 and used the basic setup for tinymce:
in ts component:
tinymce.init({
selector: '#scanning',
plugins: 'advlist link image lists',
....
});
and in html:

and I get in console errors:
global:scripts.js:14 Failed to load theme: silver from url themes/silver/theme.js
global:scripts.js:14 Failed to load icons: default from url localhost:4200/icons/default/icons.js
global:scripts.js:14 Failed to load plugin: advlist from url plugins/advlist/plugin.js
global:scripts.js:14 Failed to load model: dom from url models/dom/model.js
global:scripts.js:14 Failed to load plugin: directionality from url plugins/directionality/plugin.js
global:scripts.js:14 Failed to load plugin: lists from url plugins/lists/plugin.js
Checked in node-modules, they exist there, added in angular.json:
"scripts": [
           "node_modules/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js",
           "node_modules/tinymce/models/dom/model.js",
           "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/lists/plugin.js",
           "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/directionality/plugin.js",
           "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/advlist/plugin.js",

           "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
         
        ]

I get the same errors, had tried with min.js also, doesn't help.
